# changing style of a varying class with document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: java, html, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using woocommerce and a plugin to fit it to the needs of the german market.
I use a addon that implements delivery times.
But just in normal black colour. I actualy work with 2 delivery times, 1 - 3 and 5 - 10 days. If the delivery time is 1 - 3 days it should be displayed in green, if the delivery time is 5 - 10 days I want to see it in orange.

I already made it to change the displayed colour to my needs on static pages (products without variants like colors).
The complete css class is called "wc-gzd-additional-info delivery-time-info"

I added some java to the footer:

```js
<script type='text/javascript'>
var elementsa = document.getElementsByClassName("delivery-time-info")[0];
var elementsb = elementsa.innerHTML;
var elementsc = elementsa.innerHTML;
if (elementsb == "Lieferzeit: 1 - 3 Tage")
{ 
    elementsa.innerHTML = "<span style='color:green;font-weight:bold;'>"+elementsb+"</span>";
}
if (elementsc == "Lieferzeit: 5 - 10 Tage")
{ 
    elementsa.innerHTML = "<span style='color:orange;font-weight:bold;'>"+elementsc+"</span>";
}
</script>
```

The result in the code is for example:

```html
<p class="wc-gzd-additional-info delivery-time-info"><span style="color:orange;font-weight:bold;">Lieferzeit: 5 - 10 Tage</span></p>
```

But my problem is to make these changes to product pages WITH variants like colors for example.

The problem is that the line with

```html
<p class="wc-gzd-additional-info delivery-time-info">
```

is NOT displayed if u havent chosen a color.
After you made your decision the line changes / adds a css class element to:

```html
<p class="wc-gzd-additional-info delivery-time-info variation_modified" style="display: block;">Lieferzeit: 1 - 3 Tage</p>
```

I tried various things like changing 
document.getElementsByClassName("delivery-time-info")
to
document.getElementsByClassName("delivery-time-info"+" "+variation_modified")

and other variations.

But I think the problem is that the code changes after the page was loaded?

Any tip how to make it? Kind of rescanning the page or so?

Best regards and thank you very much!

Edit after first answer, too long to comment:
method is post I think, just scanned the code manually again and theis is what is ehind the variation button...seems like everything is already loaded...

```
<form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="658" data-product_variations="[{&quot;variation_id&quot;:662,&quot;variation_is_visible&quot;:true,&quot;variation_is_active&quot;:true,&quot;is_purchasable&quot;:true,&quot;display_price&quot;:37.37,&quot;display_regular_price&quot;:37.37,&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;attribute_farbe&quot;:&quot;Pink&quot;},&quot;image_src&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_link&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_alt&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;price_html&quot;:&quot;<span class=\&quot;price\&quot;><span class=\&quot;amount\&quot;>37,37&nbsp;€<\/span><\/span>&quot;,&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sku&quot;:&quot;440072&quot;,&quot;weight&quot;:&quot; kg&quot;,&quot;dimensions&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;min_qty&quot;:1,&quot;max_qty&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;backorders_allowed&quot;:false,&quot;is_in_stock&quot;:true,&quot;is_downloadable&quot;:false,&quot;is_virtual&quot;:false,&quot;is_sold_individually&quot;:&quot;no&quot;,&quot;variation_description&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;delivery_time&quot;:&quot;Lieferzeit: 1 - 3 Tage&quot;,&quot;unit_price&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;product_units&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;tax_info&quot;:&quot;inkl. 19% MwSt.&quot;},{&quot;variation_id&quot;:663,&quot;variation_is_visible&quot;:true,&quot;variation_is_active&quot;:true,&quot;is_purchasable&quot;:true,&quot;display_price&quot;:37.37,&quot;display_regular_price&quot;:37.37,&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;attribute_farbe&quot;:&quot;Gelb&quot;},&quot;image_src&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_link&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_alt&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;price_html&quot;:&quot;<span class=\&quot;price\&quot;><span class=\&quot;amount\&quot;>37,37&nbsp;€<\/span><\/span>&quot;,&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sku&quot;:&quot;440074&quot;,&quot;weight&quot;:&quot; kg&quot;,&quot;dimensions&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;min_qty&quot;:1,&quot;max_qty&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;backorders_allowed&quot;:false,&quot;is_in_stock&quot;:true,&quot;is_downloadable&quot;:false,&quot;is_virtual&quot;:false,&quot;is_sold_individually&quot;:&quot;no&quot;,&quot;variation_description&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;delivery_time&quot;:&quot;Lieferzeit: 1 - 3 Tage&quot;,&quot;unit_price&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;product_units&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;tax_info&quot;:&quot;inkl. 19% MwSt.&quot;},{&quot;variation_id&quot;:664,&quot;variation_is_visible&quot;:true,&quot;variation_is_active&quot;:true,&quot;is_purchasable&quot;:true,&quot;display_price&quot;:45.16,&quot;display_regular_price&quot;:45.16,&quot;attributes&quot;:{&quot;attribute_farbe&quot;:&quot;Blau&quot;},&quot;image_src&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_link&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_title&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;image_alt&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;price_html&quot;:&quot;<span class=\&quot;price\&quot;><span class=\&quot;amount\&quot;>45,16&nbsp;€<\/span><\/span>&quot;,&quot;availability_html&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;sku&quot;:&quot;440073&quot;,&quot;weight&quot;:&quot; kg&quot;,&quot;dimensions&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;min_qty&quot;:1,&quot;max_qty&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;backorders_allowed&quot;:false,&quot;is_in_stock&quot;:true,&quot;is_downloadable&quot;:false,&quot;is_virtual&quot;:false,&quot;is_sold_individually&quot;:&quot;no&quot;,&quot;variation_description&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;delivery_time&quot;:&quot;Lieferzeit: 1 - 3 Tage&quot;,&quot;unit_price&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;product_units&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;tax_info&quot;:&quot;inkl. 19% MwSt.&quot;}]">

    <table class="variations" cellspacing="0">
    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                                    <td class="product_label"><label for="farbe">Farbe</label></td>
                <td class="product_value">
                <div class="select2-container kad-select select2-dropdown-open select2-container-active" id="s2id_farbe"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">   <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-2">Pink</span><abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></a><label for="s2id_autogen2" class="select2-offscreen">Farbe</label><input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-2" id="s2id_autogen2" disabled=""></div><select id="farbe" class="kad-select select2-offscreen" name="attribute_farbe" data-attribute_name="attribute_farbe" title="Farbe" tabindex="-1"><option value="">Wählen Sie eine Ausführung</option><option value="Pink" class="attached enabled">Pink</option><option value="Gelb" class="attached enabled">Gelb</option><option value="Blau" class="attached enabled">Blau</option></select><a class="reset_variations" href="#" style="visibility: visible; display: inline;">Lösche Auswahl</a>                   </td>
                                </tr>
                </tbody>
</table>


<div class="single_variation_wrap_kad" style="display:block;">
    <div class="single_variation headerfont"><span class="price" style="display: none;"><span class="amount">37,37&nbsp;€</span></span></div>    <div class="variations_button" style="">
  <div class="quantity buttons_added"><input type="button" value="-" class="minus"><input type="number" step="1" name="quantity" value="1" title="Menge" class="input-text qty text" size="4" min="1"><input type="button" value="+" class="plus"></div>
  <button type="submit" class="kad_add_to_cart headerfont kad-btn kad-btn-primary single_add_to_cart_button">In den Warenkorb</button>
  <input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="658">
  <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="658">
  <input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="662">
</div>

</div>
```

This is a .js file which asks for specific product informations of variants:

```js
/*!
 * Variations Plugin
 */
;(function ( $, window, document, undefined ) {

 $.fn.wc_gzd_variation_form = function () {

  $.fn.wc_gzd_variation_form.reset_variation = function() {

   if ( $('.type-product').find('.org_price').length > 0 ) {
    $( '.type-product .price.variation_modified:not(.price-unit)' ).html( $('.type-product').find('.org_price').html() ).removeClass('variation_modified').show();
   }
   if ( $('.type-product').find('.org_delivery_time').length > 0 ) {
    $( '.type-product .delivery-time-info' ).html( $('.type-product').find('.org_delivery_time').html() ).removeClass('variation_modified').show();
   }
   if ( $('.type-product').find('.org_unit_price').length > 0 ) {
    $( '.type-product .unit-price' ).html( $('.product').find('.org_unit_price').html() ).removeClass('variation_modified').show();
   }
   if ( $('.type-product').find('.org_tax_info').length > 0 ) {
    $( '.type-product .tax-info' ).html( $('.product').find('.org_tax_info').html() ).removeClass('variation_modified').show();
   }
   if ( $('.type-product').find('.org_product_units').length > 0 ) {
    $( '.type-product .product-units' ).html( $('.product').find('.org_product_units').html() ).removeClass('variation_modified').show();
   }
   $('.org_product_info').remove();
   $('.variation_modified').remove();
  }

  $form = this
  $wrapper = $form.parents( '.type-product' )

  .on( 'found_variation', function( event, variation ) {
   if ( ! $wrapper.find( '.price:first' ).hasClass( 'variation_modified' ) ) {
    $wrapper.append( '<div class="org_price org_product_info">' + $wrapper.find( '.price:not(.price-unit):first' ).html() + '</div>' );
    if ( $wrapper.find( '.delivery-time-info:first' ).length > 0 )
     $wrapper.append( '<div class="org_delivery_time org_product_info">' + $wrapper.find( '.delivery-time-info:first' ).html() + '</div>' );
    if ( $wrapper.find( '.tax-info:first' ).length > 0 )
     $wrapper.append( '<div class="org_tax_info org_product_info">' + $wrapper.find( '.tax-info:first' ).html() + '</div>' );
    if ( $wrapper.find( '.price-unit:first' ).length > 0 )
     $wrapper.append( '<div class="org_unit_price org_product_info">' + $wrapper.find( '.price-unit:first' ).html() + '</div>' );
    if ( $wrapper.find( '.product-units:first' ).length > 0 )
     $wrapper.append( '<div class="org_product_units org_product_info">' + $wrapper.find( '.product-units:first' ).html() + '</div>' );
    $( '.org_product_info' ).hide();
   }
   if ( variation.price_html != '' ) {
    $( '.single_variation .price' ).hide();
    $wrapper.find( '.price:not(.price-unit):first' ).html( variation.price_html ).addClass( 'variation_modified' );
   }
   $wrapper.find( '.delivery-time-info:first' ).hide();
   $wrapper.find( '.price-unit:first' ).hide();
   $wrapper.find( '.tax-info:first' ).hide();
   $wrapper.find( '.product-units:first' ).hide();

   if ( variation.delivery_time != '' )
    $wrapper.find( 'p.delivery-time-info:first' ).html( variation.delivery_time ).addClass('variation_modified').show();
   if ( variation.tax_info != '' )
    $wrapper.find( '.tax-info:first' ).html( variation.tax_info ).addClass('variation_modified').show();
   if ( variation.unit_price != '' ) {
    $wrapper.find( '.price-unit:first' ).remove();
    $wrapper.find( 'div[itemprop="offers"]:first' ).after('<p class="price price-unit smaller variation_modified">' + variation.unit_price + '</p>').show();
   }
   if ( variation.product_units != '' ) {
    $wrapper.find( '.product-units:first' ).remove();
    $wrapper.find( '.product_meta' ).prepend('<span class="product-units-wrapper product-units variation_modified">' + variation.product_units + '</span>').show();
   }
  })

  // Check variations
  .on( 'update_variation_values', function( event, matching_variations ) {
   setTimeout(function() {
           if ( ! $('.single_variation_wrap').is(':visible') ) {
            $.fn.wc_gzd_variation_form.reset_variation();
           }
          }, 250); 
  })

  .on( 'click', '.reset_variations', function( event ) {
   $.fn.wc_gzd_variation_form.reset_variation();
  });

 };

 $( function() {

  // wc_add_to_cart_variation_params is required to continue, ensure the object exists
  if ( typeof wc_add_to_cart_variation_params === 'undefined' )
   return false;
  $( '.variations_form' ).wc_gzd_variation_form();
  $( '.variations_form .variations select' ).change();
  $( '.variations_form .variations input:radio:checked' ).change();
 });

})( jQuery, window, document );
```

I actualy cant make itt o edit the variations because the way I tried above has to rescan after each "chose ofa  variation".

Comment: Your "rescanning" hunch is correct. You need to somehow listen for the delivery time changing and then run your code again. E.g. if delivery time is selected via a `<select>` then listen for a `change` event on that element.

Comment: method is post I think, just scanned the code manually again and theis is what is ehind the variation button...seems like everything is already loaded...look above please, added it to original post

Comment: How are you generating the delivery time information? Are the delivery times specific to each variation? I'm having a hard time understanding what is happening with all your different code blocks. Could you somehow simplify it for my poor, jet-lagged brain?

Comment: Hey :) I think the problem is not about your jetlag, its about that i am confused by myself ;) I try to explain it. The delivery time is set as a wp_term 1 for each delivery time generated for example id 55 = 1 - 3 days, 56 = 5 - 10 days. I just found a .js file which asks for the product conditions  I edited the original post with it.

Answer (score 0):

[SOLVED]

Okay it is way more easy....

just go to wp_terms look for the right row and change the name from "1 - 3 Tage" to

```html
<span style='color:green;font-weight:bold;'>1 - 3 Tage</span>
```

I tried to enter it like that in the wp backend, didnt work.

But worked by entering it via phpmyadmin.

Thanks everybody and best regards!